# Cython, setuptools extra_link_args ipo: warning #11016: Warning unknown option --start-group

Tags: python, c++, linker, cython, setuptools

I want to link my cythonized cpp file with another object file for which I require the following linker arguments

```
-Wl,--start-group ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a -Wl,--end-group
```

If I add this in my setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import os

os.environ["CXX"] = "icc"
os.environ["CC"] = "icc"
setup(ext_modules = cythonize(Extension(
   "test",
   sources=["test.pyx"],
   language="c++",
   extra_objects=["mylib.o"],
   libraries=["pthread", "m", "dl"],
   extra_link_args=["-qopenmp", "-xHOST",
   '-Wl,--start-group ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a -Wl,--end-group']
), language_level=3))
```

it produces the following warning during linking:

```
ipo: warning #11016: Warning unknown option --start-group ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a -Wl
```

It seems like the `-Wl,--start-group` flag is split at the `,`. Does this make any sense? How can I get my setup.py to work?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `extra_link_args =[..., "-Wl,--start-group", "${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a", "${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a", "${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a", "-Wl,--end-group"]`, i.e. not one big string, but may small?

Comment: I tried this as well, but it yields even more errors.., like
`icc: error #10236: File not found:  '${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a'
icc: error #10236: File not found:  '${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a'
icc: error #10236: File not found:  '${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a'`

Comment: Ok, you are a step further - this time `${MKLROOT}` is not replaced by the right value. You need to read it (os.environ) ad replace it with the right value in your script.

Comment: Excellent, this did the job! Thanks alot